# Json to features using esri git hub tool not working for ST_Buffer

Tags: hadoop, hive, gis, esri

My objective is to create a buffer of 1000 m for enode. I am able to obtain a json using the copy from HDFS tool. But I am unable to create a feature class using json to features tool. 
I used the following query

> CREATE external table enodebuffer (shape binary) 
>   INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE enodebuffer
>   SELECT ST_Buffer(enodeaggregate.shape,100) from enodeaggregate;
>   I am able to obtain the count and retrieve the columns.Copy from HDFS to obtain a json file also works successfully.

When I convert json to features using the git hub tool I get
Failed to execute json to features and I get the following description for the error as shown in the image below.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUE7X.png)

I tried the same query creating a table using multiple columns with the shape column but I get the same error as shown above.

Any info would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a custom spatial reference?  What is the 'spatialReference' value in your JSON data?   https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError  https://github.com/Esri/geoprocessing-tools-for-hadoop/blob/master/JSONUtil.py#L21..L24  [GIS-tools collaborator]

Comment: Hi randall. It seems to work fine now. I am not sure how. I tried using the ST_SRID function. But even without the SRID function I am able to convert json to features, but without the projection system.

Comment: "without the projection system" - if you mean it is imported to a feature class but without the right spatial reference, you can specify the spatial reference in ArcGIS desktop as I had to do in the [Vehicle Trip Discovery article](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/08/09/vehicle-trip-discovery-with-gis-tools-for-hadoop/#toarcmap).